# Influxdb not asking for authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, influxdb

I Have installed influxdb on a linux distro running on a raspberrypi...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ influx -version
InfluxDB shell version: 1.1.1
```

Then i create a DB, followed by an Admin user with

```
CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'password' WITH ALL PRIVILEGES
```

After this i edit the influx.conf file located at:

```
/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

As i want the influxdb to ask for user auth when it is accessed (http external or internal and console?is it possible console?) i browse and look for the [[http]] block on the file.... this is what i have.

```
###
### [http]
###
### Controls how the HTTP endpoints are configured. These are the primary
### mechanism for getting data into and out of InfluxDB.
###
# [http]
  # Determines whether HTTP endpoint is enabled.
   enabled = true

  # The bind address used by the HTTP service.
  # bind-address = ":8086"

  # Determines whether HTTP authentication is enabled.
   auth-enabled = true

  # The default realm sent back when issuing a basic auth challenge.
  # realm = "InfluxDB"

  # Determines whether HTTP request logging is enable.d
  # log-enabled = true

  # Determines whether detailed write logging is enabled.
  # write-tracing = false

  # Determines whether the pprof endpoint is enabled.  This endpoint is used for
  # troubleshooting and monitoring.
  pprof-enabled = true

  # Determines whether HTTPS is enabled.
  https-enabled = false

  # The SSL certificate to use when HTTPS is enabled.
  https-certificate = "/etc/ssl/influxdb.pem"

  # Use a separate private key location.
  https-private-key = ""

  # The JWT auth shared secret to validate requests using JSON web tokens.
  shared-sercret = ""

  # The default chunk size for result sets that should be chunked.
  # max-row-limit = 10000

  # The maximum number of HTTP connections that may be open at once.  New connections that
  # would exceed this limit are dropped.  Setting this value to 0 disables the limit.
  # max-connection-limit = 0

  # Enable http service over unix domain socket
  # unix-socket-enabled = false

  # The path of the unix domain socket.
  # bind-socket = "/var/run/influxdb.sock"
```

Changing the 1st and 3rd sub-group entries.

Finnaly i restart the influxdb service with:

```
sudo service influxdb restart
```

**Problems**

1 - Creating a database from another computer on the network (without login tokens) is successful (and it shouldn't):

```
http://192.168.7.125:8086/query?q=CREATE DATABASE test
```

returns:

```
{

"results": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

calling influxdb on raspberry cmdline does not ask for auth:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ influx
Visit https://enterprise.influxdata.com to register for updates, InfluxDB server management, and monitoring.
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.1.1
InfluxDB shell version: 1.1.1
>
```

**Does anyone know what am i doing wrong?**

**EDIT**

Furthermore, checking the /var/log/syslog i can see that:
1- It is loading the file from the currect directory

```
[run] 2017/01/17 11:27:36 InfluxDB starting, version 1.1.1, branch master, commit e47c
f1f2e83a02443d7115c54f838be8ee959644
Jan 17 11:27:36 raspberrypi influxd[901]: [run] 2017/01/17 11:27:36 Go version go1.7.4, GOMAXPROCS set to 4
Jan 17 11:27:36 raspberrypi influxd[901]: [run] 2017/01/17 11:27:36 Using configuration at: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
Jan 17 11:27:36 raspberrypi influxd[901]: [store] 2017/01/17 11:27:36 Using data dir: /var/lib/influxdb/data
```

2- It fails in starting with authentication (auth is deactivated)

```
Jan 17 11:27:37 raspberrypi influxd[901]: [httpd] 2017/01/17 11:27:37 Starting HTTP service
Jan 17 11:27:37 raspberrypi influxd[901]: [httpd] 2017/01/17 11:27:37 Authentication enabled: false
Jan 17 11:27:37 raspberrypi influxd[901]: [httpd] 2017/01/17 11:27:37 Listening on HTTP: [::]:8086
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is on the **[http]** here:

```
###
### [http]
###
### Controls how the HTTP endpoints are configured. These are the primary
### mechanism for getting data into and out of InfluxDB.
###
[http]
  # Determines whether HTTP endpoint is enabled.
   enabled = true

  # The bind address used by the HTTP service.
  # bind-address = ":8086"

  # Determines whether HTTP authentication is enabled.
   auth-enabled = true
```

Comment: What was the solution? I cant really tell.

Comment: The [http] had a # and it shouldn't

Comment: This answers why http requests didn't have functional authentication, now we still need to answer how to enable authentication when using 'influx' command locally though cli.

Comment: For anyone still visiting this and wondering about the comment by @valentt. It parses the authentication on running commands, but not on connecting. You will be able to connect with auth enabled, you just will not be able to run any queries without authenticating first

Comment: Great hint Imre_G! I just could not understand why I still was able to login via CLI but you were right: Executing commands is not possible then...