# Why can any user login influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

I have installed influxdb. But in the server every user can login when ther type inlux.

Why is it like that? Is not it a security problem. And how can I solve it?

I want to login with spesific admin user and its admin password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Influxdb not asking for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696079/influxdb-not-asking-for-authentication)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The "why"

Different databases have used reasonings with minor differences over the years, but basically, it goes like this:

> In its most simple install, `<insert DBMS here>` should just run - for integration tests, simple evaluation purposes etc. We **could** generate a root/admin/superhoncho user password, but more often than not, this is not going to be changed, and that is a *Bad Thing™*.
>
> And since nobody sane would run a database in production ***without*** authentication and authorisation enabled, providing easy access in the default installation is not a problem anyway, is it?

I tend to agree with this reasoning, though I am off the opinion that in the case the DBMS has authentication and authorisation disabled per default, it should bind to `localhost` by default, too. You make your DBMS accessible to the outside world, and be it only your company's network?  You surely have thought about the implications!

## The "how"

### Authentication

I am going to use docker to illustrate it and it is quite obvious what you have to do in a non-docker environment.

First, we pull the influxdb docker image and create a default config file in one go:

```
$ docker run --rm influxdb influxd config > influxdb.conf
Unable to find image 'influxdb:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/influxdb
...
Digest: sha256:0aa7fea5336b5e5cc1c80e16062865821ec772e06519c138947ef5ebd9b34907
Status: Downloaded newer image for influxdb:latest
Merging with configuration at: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

Now we change the authentication parameter in the `[http]` section of our `influxdb.conf` to true:

```
...
[http]
  auth-enabled = true
...
```

Next, we start our InfluxDB using this modified config file:

```
$ docker run -d --name influxdb -p 8086:8086 \
      -v $PWD/influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:ro \
      influxdb -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
1987f962c331d2404a2564bb752d971553b13181dbbbb1e38cf50d345b3191c4
```

(The hash sum you get will be different.)

Now, we connect to our influxdb and create the admin user

```
$ docker exec -it influxdb influx
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.7.8
InfluxDB shell version: 1.7.8
> create user admin with password 'secret' with all privileges;
```

> **From this point on, credentials are needed for pretty much everything**

```
> show users
ERR: unable to parse authentication credentials
Warning: It is possible this error is due to not setting a database.
Please set a database with the command "use <database>".
> auth
username: admin
password: 
> show users
user  admin
----  -----
admin true
```

### Authorization

Simple mnemonic: "Users are granted permissions per database." So, in order to grant something to a user, that user must first exist:

```
> create user berkancetin with password 'supersecret';
> create database foobar
> grant read on foobar to berkancetin
> show users
user        admin
----        -----
admin       true
berkancetin false
> show grants for "berkancetin"
database privilege
-------- ---------
foobar   READ
```

## Further reading (!!!)

Ignore at your own risk. ***You. Have. Been. Warned.***

- [InfluxDB authentication](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/authentication_and_authorization/#authentication)
- [InfluxDB docs on Authorization](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/authentication_and_authorization/#authorization)

Comment: Great article! Easy to copy.